# how do I use select control in my controller?

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to define the select control in my controller but it isn't working. I want the select control to have a default value {garows>Type} and show drop down that has Question, Answer, and Button.

This is what I have tried so far. The select is the third control in ColumnListItem. Every thing else is working.

```
this.setModel(new JSONModel({
        "type": {
            "answer": "Answer",
            "button": "Button",
            "question": "Question"
        }
}), "typDropDown");

var item = new Item({
    text: "{garows>/Type}"
});

var oTable = this.byId("gaTable");
oTable.setMode("None");
oTable.bindItems({ //changes the table for guided assistance qa to editable 
    path: "garows>/flow",
    template: new ColumnListItem({
    cells: [
        new Text({
            text: "{garows>ID}"
        }),
        new TextArea({
            value: "{garows>value_long}",
            growing: true,
            growingMaxLines: 7
        }),
        new Select({
            autoAdjustWidth: true
        }).bindAggregation("items", "typDropDown>/type", item),
        new TextArea({
            value: "{garows>Action}"
        }),
        new TextArea({
            value: "{garows>Button1}"
        }),
        new TextArea({
            value: "{garows>Button2}"
        }),
        new TextArea({
                value: "{garows>Button3}"
        }),
        new TextArea({
            value: "{garows>Button4}"
        }),
        new TextArea({
            value: "{garows>Button5}"
        }),
        new TextArea({
            value: "{garows>Button6}"
        }),
        new TextArea({
            value: "{garows>Active_Flag}"
        })

        ]
     }),
     key: "ID"
}).setKeyboardMode("Edit");
```

The expected result is, select control will have a default value {garows>Type} and show drop down that has Question, Answer, and Button. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the data structure of your typDropDown is not correct - it needs to be an array and not an object map for the aggregation binding.

If I understand you correctly you need to bind the items aggregation to the typDropDown model (which needs to be an array) and you want to bind the selectedKey property of the Select to a value in the garows model.

So in my opionion you need to change the data structure of typeDropDown AND the item template AND you need to bind selectedKey.

Answer (score 0):

On your bindAgregation it should be

```
 .bindAggregation("items", "garows>/type", item) right?
```

You used a different model (typDropDown).

Comment: Just tried that but it did not work either. The default value should be {garows>Type} and the three drop down values are in the model typDropDown>/type.